# Анимация между активити

Tags: android, анимация

Здравствуйте. Нужно сделать следующую анимацию между двумя активити.
Вторая активити выезжает слева направо, поверх первой. В конце метод finish().
Из второй активити нужно возвращаться в первую, сдвигом второй активити, поверх первой обратно(т.е. справа налево).
Вроде бы простая анимация, но т.к. первая активити уничтожается, не понятно как такое реализовать.

Comment: не вызывайте finish.

Comment: Мне нужно завершать работу активити.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите задать собственную анимацию при переключении между активностями, то можете сделать это несколькими способами.

У класса Activity есть метод overridePendingTransition() и он должен идти сразу после вызова метода startActivity() или finish(). Метод принимает два параметра: ресурс анимации для запускающей активности и ресурс анимации для уходящей активности.

Таким образом вам нужно создать в папке res/anim два файла анимации и передать их идентификаторы в метод.

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/overridependingtransition.php

P.s. По личному опыту , использование анимации для активностей является плохим тоном. 
Обычно для этих целей используются фрагменты.

Comment: Это я всё знаю. Я сделал анимацию, когда вторая активити выезжает слева направо, поверх первой. И обратно, первая активити выезжает справа налево, поверх второй. Мне нужно, чтобы вторая активити возвращалась поверх первой.

Comment: Только фрагменты тогда